# Does Kotlin await in order in parameters?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Does Kotlin await exactly strictly in order

1. recipient.await()
2. msg.await()

at line 7:

```
 suspend fun sendEmail(r: String, msg: String): Boolean { //(6)
        delay(2000)
        println("Sent '$msg' to $r")
        return true
    }

    suspend fun getReceiverAddressFromDatabase(): String { //(4)
        delay(1000)
        return "coroutine@kotlin.org"
    }

    suspend fun sendEmailSuspending(): Boolean {
        val msg = async(CommonPool) {             //(3)
            delay(500)
            "The message content"
        }
        val recipient = async(CommonPool) {  //(5)
            getReceiverAddressFromDatabase()  
        } 
        println("Waiting for email data")
        val sendStatus = async(CommonPool) {
            sendEmail(recipient.await(), msg.await()) //(7)
        }
        return sendStatus.await() //(8)
    }
```

or in any order? I mean does Kotlin check first for recipient.await() and only after it completes go for check for msg.await()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't `await`-specific and cuts much deeper, down to the evaluation order semantics of Kotlin itself.

So, here's a quote from the [Kotlin language specification](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlin-spec/):

> Function arguments are then evaluated in the order of their appearance in the function call left-to-right

Applied to your line of code:

```
sendEmail(recipient.await(), msg.await())
```

it is clear that first `recipient.await()` is evaluated and then `msg.await()`. The `await()` call doesn't complete until the `Deferred` in question has been completed.